# makefile, process several files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, lint

How can i process several files in a makefile (gnu make), and:

- run one command or a series of commands for each file
- fail on a single error code larger than zero
- no need to type every single filename in the makefile
- continue to run on all files even after first failure

I've come up with this. it works, except for the last requirement, and is very unMake:

```
.PHONY: lint
.PHONY: all

all: lint

lint:
    for f in `find src/ -name \*.inc -o -name \*.html`; do php -l $$f && continue || exit 1; done
```

Comment: "fail on a single error code larger than zero"
"continue to run on all files even after first failure"
Uhh...

Comment: Sounds like a script is more suitable than a Makefile?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: it should run on all files, so the command can output all the errors. But if any of them returned >0 the make rule should fail in the build chain.

Comment: indeed, i agree now that a script is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more make-like transcription of your orignal makefile:

```
files := $(shell find src/ -name \*.inc -o -name \*.html)
.PHONY: ${files}
${files}: ; php -l $@

.PHONY: lint
lint: ${files} ; echo Lint finished
```

I really *really* do not like the use of `$(shell…)` in makefiles. Personally I would list all the files in the Makefile, perhaps with a target to assert that the list is complete.

If you require your last point ("continue to run on all files even after first failure") then use `make -k`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to rewrite it to be more in make style, i.e. something like this:

```
files = ....

lint_targets = $(addsuffix .lint, $(files))

lint: $(lint_targets)

.PHONY: lint $(lint_targets)

$(lint_targets): 
    @php -l $(basename $@)
```

Comment: The only trouble is that the `$(files)` rules will never be run. (Since the rule has no prerequisites, it will run only if the target does not exist, and since the target list was created by `find`, that's never.)

Comment: @Beta you may be surprised but prerequisites are not mandatory; it'll run if you add suffix to all files for example; my proposal has nothing to do with find; it's an alternative way to apply some tool to selected files